# Line clipping to arbitary 2D polygon

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry, numeric

If I get a line segment which was long enough to cross a given polygon, which could be concave or convex polygon. How did I find the all the intersected light segments which was contained in the polygon?

[image]

If the target region is not polygon, but a implicit curve function or spline curve, how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really isn't a simple solution to your problem, especially with curves (beziers and splines). On top of the complexities of polygon clipping, there's the considerable challenge of reconstructing the clipped curves (assuming you want the clipping result to remain as beziers and splines and not just 'flattened' line approximations).

I have recently released a beta update* to my polygon clipping library 'Clipper' that does do line-polygon and line-line clipping (where lines can be curves too). However, while the main library is written in Delphi, C++ & C#, the new beta code is so far only in Delphi which may not help you. Nevertheless if you look at the code you'll see why I state there's no 'simple' solution.

- Edit 15 Jul 2011:
  This 'update' never got beyond this beta release and is now simply 'proof-of-concept'. It is now based on an old version of my Clipper library and would need a major rewrite to be maintainable and extensible. (At some stage I may revisit it but I'm currently intent on further improving the core library.) Nevertheless, this 'proof-of-concept' Delphi code can be downloaded [here](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper_lines_polys.zip)

[image: Clipper demo image]

Comment: Thanks. Which method did you use for curves clipping?

Comment: The approach I took was initially to flatten the curves (and labeling each flattened segment) since the clipping algorithm works on lines only. Once intersections are found the labeled segments are used to identify the curve sub-segments (de Casteljau's algorithm). Then it's a matter of reapplying the de Casteljau's algorithm to the original curve, but only to the portions of the curve that contain intersections. Does that make sense?

Comment: I would be interested in seeing this functionality (specifically line-polygon clipping) added to the clipper library (including the C# translation).

Comment: Hi, is this algorithm included in your latest version of Clipper?

Comment: It is, and with a C# demo. However, it's currently undergoing significant revision so expect changes hopefully in the next Clipper update.

Comment: Sorry I can't find it, I would like to implement intersection test for lines and polygons. And extract every connected components, is this possible? In the image above, I should get 4 components.

Answer (score 3):

- Step one: find all intersection
  points, in any order. For polygon,
  you need to find intersection of red
  line and line of each segment. Just solve system of two linear equations. If solution is constrained to polygon segment limits, you
  have an intersection.
- Step two: sort found points by
  position on red line. You know that first and last point are outer ones. "Outerness" flips with each point - outer-inner-outer and so on. Between two adjacent outer points you have inner line segment (green). Edit: not true... Start with point #0, segment #0 - #1 is inner, next is outer, next is inner again and so on.

If region is not polygon, but is given by some implicit function, you need to find where that function is equal to red line (approach depends on function, of course).

Comment: Maybe I need to give a complex polygon.

Comment: How to sort them. It's hard to find the in/out relationship I think. The intersection point list depends on the polygon edges.

Comment: How to sort? Find point with lowest coordinates and sort all other ones by the distance to that point.

Comment: Thanks. Is there some reference related to this issue?

Comment: This is known problem, there should be many. Try to search for "line polygon intersection".

Comment: The first green intersection point is inner? Second green intersection point is outer?

Comment: I used wrong words. The points are not inner/outer, first line segment between green points is inner, next is outer and so on.

Comment: You need to be careful with this approach as if the line intersects a vertex of the polygon, you'll see two points where you would really expect one. They may also not have exactly the same value, due to floating point imprecision.