# Polygon crossed by line

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, graphics2d

I have polygon and a line.

```
g.drawLine(this.getLine().getP1().getX(), this.getLine().getP1().getY(),
                this.getLine().getP2().getX(), this.getLine().getP2().getY());

g.drawPolygon(this.polygon);
```

and I have to find the cross-points between the polygon and the line(if any), and what part of the line is in the polygon. Any ideas how to do that .

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: @michael667 - sounds more like an analytical geometry question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940694/line-clipping-to-arbitary-2d-polygon#3944295

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, the problem can be reduced to finding the [*intersection of two lines*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection). Each pair of lines consists of the original line and a line obtained from the [`PathIterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html) of the [`Polygon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html). There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877646/adding-a-point-to-polygon/5878090#5878090).