# Function that returns intersection of two TShapes, including TPaths?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Anyone have any knowledge of a function that returns the intersection TPath for two TShapes? Especially one that returns the intersection TPath of two TPaths.

For instance:

```
pthIntersection := PathIntersection(Path1,Path2);
```

[image]

Comment: I like the question, but next time, please include a picture of what you are trying to achieve, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940694/line-clipping-to-arbitary-2d-polygon for an example of effective use of graphics in a question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no built-in function for this.
But what I think you are trying to do is this:

Given a polygon (aka TPath) made up for distinct points connected by lines.
Return all points in ShapeA that lay inside ShapeB.

**Point intersection**
This can be done using [`PointInObjectLocal`](http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.15/libraries/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.PointInObjectLocal).
Run a loop visiting all points in `PathA` and see if any lay inside `PathB`.

**Line intersection**
If you want to know all vertices that overlap you'll first have to `Flatten` (a copy) of both TPaths and then run a line intersect algorithm for all lines in both shapes.
This converts all curves to lines.

Here's a routine to do just that:
From: http://www.partow.net/projects/fastgeo/index.html

```
function Intersect(const x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4: TFloat; out ix, iy: TFloat): boolean;
var
  UpperX, UpperY, LowerX, LowerY: TFloat;
  Ax, Bx, Cx, Ay, By, Cy: TFloat;
  D, F, E, Ratio: TFloat;
begin
  Result:= false;

  Ax:= x2 - x1;
  Bx:= x3 - x4;

  if Ax < Zero then begin
    LowerX:= x2;
    UpperX:= x1;
  end else begin
    UpperX:= x2;
    LowerX:= x1;
  end;

  if Bx > Zero then begin
    if (UpperX < x4) or (x3 < LowerX) then Exit;
  end else if (UpperX < x3) or (x4 < LowerX) then Exit;

  Ay:= y2 - y1;
  By:= y3 - y4;

  if Ay < Zero then begin
    LowerY:= y2;
    UpperY:= y1;
  end else begin
    UpperY:= y2;
    LowerY:= y1;
  end;

  if By > Zero then begin
    if (UpperY < y4) or (y3 < LowerY) then Exit;
  end else if (UpperY < y3) or (y4 < LowerY) then Exit;

  Cx:= x1 - x3;
  Cy:= y1 - y3;
  D:= (By * Cx) - (Bx * Cy);
  F:= (Ay * Bx) - (Ax * By);

  if F > Zero then begin
    if (D < Zero) or (D > F) then Exit;
  end else if (D > Zero) or (D < F) then Exit;

  E:= (Ax * Cy) - (Ay * Cx);

  if F > Zero then begin
    if (E < Zero) or (E > F) then Exit;
  end else if (E > Zero) or (E < F) then Exit;

  Result:= true;

  Ratio:= (Ax * -By) - (Ay * -Bx);

  if NotEqual(Ratio, Zero) then begin
    Ratio:= ((Cy * -Bx) - (Cx * -By)) / Ratio;
    ix:= x1 + (Ratio * Ax);
    iy:= y1 + (Ratio * Ay);
  end else begin
    //if Collinear(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) then
    if IsEqual((Ax * -Cy), ( -Cx * Ay)) then begin
      ix:= x3;
      iy:= y3;
    end else begin
      ix:= x4;
      iy:= y4;
    end;
  end;
end;

function Intersect(const Segment1,Segment2:TSegment2D; out ix, iy : TFloat):Boolean;
begin
  Result := Intersect(Segment1[1].x,Segment1[1].y,Segment1[2].x,Segment1[2].y,Segment2[1].x,Segment2[1].y,Segment2[2].x,Segment2[2].y,ix,iy);
end;
```

Just convert the `TFloat` x,y pairs to `TPointF` and you're in business.
The cool thing about the routine is that it also tells you the exact point at which the lines overlap.

If you follow the lines, until two lines overlap and from there on start tracking both overlapping lines and PointInShape you can construct an exact image of the overlap of the two shapes.

**Making it faster**
If the flattening and the corresponding increase in the number of line segments make your code too slow you can keep the curves and see if a line/curve intersects another curve.
For this you can convert the curves into [bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and use [De_Casteljau's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm)

**More info**
See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940694/line-clipping-to-arbitary-2d-polygon) and the [link to Delphi source code](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper_lines_polys.zip) in its first or second answer.

Comment: Dankie, Johan. I was afraid I had to take the hard road and had already started along that path (no pun intended) after no one came with a TPath solution. Since my issue concerns mostly bezier curves, I'll look into the links too.